# Pinniped cli not working on windows from CMD and Powershell

Tags: kubernetes, openid-connect, vmware, tanzu-application-service

pinniped cli is not working in widnows.
pinniped-cli-windows-amd64.exe is downloaded but when i type pinniped, it's not recognized.

C:\Users\hello>pinniped
pinniped is not recognized as a internal command or external command, operable program or batch file.

Seem windows is not recognizing this .exe file as published by a valid publisher.

pinniped should show the pinniped cli options and be recognized as command. I created a folder called pinniped and copied .exe file and tried ...that did work.

Comment: https://pinniped.dev/docs/howto/install-cli/  - DOWNLOAD V0.22.0 FOR WINDOWS/AMD64 try downloading .exe file from this link and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi `Chai` I have gone through the link and tried installing pinniped cli it throwed me same error, then I troubleshooted and found that pinniped cli’s executable file is not getting added to the path and we can run pinniped commands by executing the exe file, however everytime you need to go to the directory where your pinniped-cli.exe file is present. Inorder to resolve this you can add pinniped cli’s exe to you path and it will solve your problem, follow this [document](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/) for more information.

Comment: only if given full path C:\Users\hello\pinniped-cli-windows-amd64.exe .. it's working ..even after adding environment variable ... it;s not working @Kranthiveer Dontineni

Comment: C:\Users\hello>pinniped-cli-windows-amd64.exe version is working

Comment: @Chai then it seems a bug with pinniped cli you need to raise a bug request with them.

Comment: @Chai you can open a new issue [here](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/pinniped/issues) upvote or accept this answer if this helped you. So that community members can follow this for reference

Comment: I opened the issue with Pinniped from the link you provided. Once it's resolved.. we should be good.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue, so i had purged the cache here: C:\Users\user.kube\cache

And then, i have modified the path of the program pinniped in the config file below, at the line **command**  (obviously, the program pinniped itself has to be present in this path) :

C:\Users\user.kube\config

- name: cluster-np-a2op-cluster-pinniped
  user:
  exec:
  apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1

.....
.....
.....

- --upstream-identity-provider-flow=browser_authcode
  command: **C:\Program Files\Pinniped\pinniped.exe**

env: []

.....
.....
.....

Hope this will help.

;)